# Why can't my nullable int be null? InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two tables:

```
public partial class CHILD
{
    public string PID_CHILD { get; set; }    
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ID_CHILD { get; set; }
}

public partial class PARENT
{
    public string ID_PARENT { get; set; }
    public int? ID_CHILD { get; set; }
    public List<CHILD> Childs { get; set; }
}
```

In PARENT, the column ID_CHILD can be null, but I need to map them together in fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PARENT>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasMany(a => a.Childs)
            .WithOne()
            .HasPrincipalKey(a => a.ID_CHILD)
            .HasForeignKey(b => b.ID_CHILD);
}
```

But when I do this for example :

```
var test = context.PARENT.ToList();
```

I have this error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidCastException: La colonne contient des données NULL (Column contain null data)
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetInt32(int i)
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Because `int` is not nullable, but `int?` is. You probably need `public int? ID_CHILD { get; set; }` in your `Child`-class. Btw: the plural of child is children :)

Comment: It looks like you've nulled the type on the parent table but not on the child table?

Comment: @HimBromBeere, I just made the change, it's not that ...

Comment: @DylanSchmitt shouldn't the principal key be `ID_PARENT` ? In a one-to-many relation what would be the value of the paren't `ID_CHILD` field? In fact, you probably don't even need `HasPrincipalKey` unless you intend to use a different parent ID field in the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint. As the doc says: `ypically you would only call this method if you want to use a property(s) other than the primary key as the principal property(s). `

Comment: Who/what is calling `OracleDataReader.GetIn32(int i)` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I need to use ID_CHILD of PARENT for my FOREIGN KEY constraint, this is why I use HasPrincipalKey

Comment: Looks like either `CHILD.ID` or `CHILD.ID_CHILD` are nullable in the database (meaning that EF didn't create the database).

Comment: @GertArnold In fact, EF didn't create the database, it's an existing old database ..

Comment: Yes, I figured that, so what about the fields being nullable?

Answer (score 2):

Check on your database if you allow null values for this column,

your are trying to create a class many to one and one to one at the same time try to change your classes like:

```
public partial class CHILD
{
    public string PID_CHILD { get; set; }    
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ID_PARENT { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ID_PARENT")]
    public PARENT Parent {get;set;}
}

public partial class PARENT
{
    public string ID_PARENT { get; set; }
    public List<CHILD> Childs { get; set; }
}
```

there is the error:

```
public partial class PARENT
{
    public string ID_PARENT { get; set; }
    public int? ID_CHILD { get; set; } (one to one)
    public List<CHILD> Childs { get; set; } (many to one)
}
```

You don't need specify the ID_CHILD (Parent class and Parent table) if you want many to one, you already have done this on the CHILD class and I suppose in the table
if you want one to one need to be like:

```
public partial class PARENT
{
    public string ID_PARENT { get; set; }
    public int? ID_CHILD { get; set; }
    public CHILD Child { get; set; }
}
```

https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx